# default "appengine connected Android project" 500 error

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-messaging, google-plugin-eclipse

I am struglling to figure out how to get the default "appengine connected Android project" to work.
I am using eclipse Luna (4.4.2) with the google plugin (Using google app engine SDK 1.9.18).
I created the default project by entering the relevant scopes (project name, package name, API key and project number).
then I started the local webserver by running xxxxx-AppEngine as a web application.
Then as soon as I try to access: http://localhost:8888/ I get the following error in my console:

מרץ 22, 2015

```
11:55:33 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error for /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.Types$NativeTypeVariableEquals
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.TypeResolver$TypeTable.resolveInternal(TypeResolver.java:296)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.TypeResolver$TypeTable.resolve(TypeResolver.java:249)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.TypeResolver.resolveType(TypeResolver.java:160)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.TypeResolver.resolveTypes(TypeResolver.java:176)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.TypeResolver.resolveParameterizedType(TypeResolver.java:200)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.TypeResolver.resolveType(TypeResolver.java:162)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken.resolveType(TypeToken.java:245)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken.resolveSupertype(TypeToken.java:256)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken.getGenericInterfaces(TypeToken.java:333)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.config.Serializers.getSerializerClasses(Serializers.java:143)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.config.annotationreader.ApiAnnotationIntrospector.findSerializerInstance(ApiAnnotationIntrospector.java:215)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.config.annotationreader.ApiAnnotationIntrospector.findSerializer(ApiAnnotationIntrospector.java:99)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.config.annotationreader.ApiAnnotationIntrospector.findSerializer(ApiAnnotationIntrospector.java:44)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector$Pair.findSerializer(AnnotationIntrospector.java:1146)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.findSerializerFromAnnotation(BasicSerializerFactory.java:362)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:252)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:782)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:735)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:344)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:420)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:601)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectWriter._configAndWriteValue(ObjectWriter.java:456)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectWriter.writeValueAsString(ObjectWriter.java:393)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.response.ServletResponseResultWriter.writeValueAsString(ServletResponseResultWriter.java:183)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.response.ServletResponseResultWriter.writeError(ServletResponseResultWriter.java:83)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:387)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:160)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

מרץ 22, 2015 11:55:33 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: /_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/deviceinfoendpoint/v1/rest: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 500
מרץ 22, 2015 11:55:33 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error for /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.Types$NativeTypeVariableEquals
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.TypeResolver$TypeTable.resolveInternal(TypeResolver.java:296)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.TypeResolver$TypeTable.resolve(TypeResolver.java:249)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.TypeResolver.resolveType(TypeResolver.java:160)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.TypeResolver.resolveTypes(TypeResolver.java:176)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.TypeResolver.resolveParameterizedType(TypeResolver.java:200)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.TypeResolver.resolveType(TypeResolver.java:162)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken.resolveType(TypeToken.java:245)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken.resolveSupertype(TypeToken.java:256)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken.getGenericInterfaces(TypeToken.java:333)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.config.Serializers.getSerializerClasses(Serializers.java:143)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.config.annotationreader.ApiAnnotationIntrospector.findSerializerInstance(ApiAnnotationIntrospector.java:215)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.config.annotationreader.ApiAnnotationIntrospector.findSerializer(ApiAnnotationIntrospector.java:99)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.config.annotationreader.ApiAnnotationIntrospector.findSerializer(ApiAnnotationIntrospector.java:44)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector$Pair.findSerializer(AnnotationIntrospector.java:1146)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.findSerializerFromAnnotation(BasicSerializerFactory.java:362)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:252)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:782)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:735)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:344)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:420)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:601)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectWriter._configAndWriteValue(ObjectWriter.java:456)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectWriter.writeValueAsString(ObjectWriter.java:393)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.response.ServletResponseResultWriter.writeValueAsString(ServletResponseResultWriter.java:183)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.response.ServletResponseResultWriter.writeError(ServletResponseResultWriter.java:83)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:387)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:160)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

מרץ 22, 2015 11:55:33 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: /_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/messageEndpoint/v1/rest: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve API configs with status: 500
```

forthermore, when I run the android client and push "REGISTER", I get the same 500 error.

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: I just updated to gae's sdk version 1.9.18, and now I have this exact same issue.  Have you solved it?

Comment: Update from my end. I filed an issue for this. Note I found a (bad) workaround listed at the bottom of the issue. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11834

Comment: Update #2: I found the solution!  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29323463/1836506) below.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem today when I updated to GAE's SDK version 1.9.18.  Finally I figured out the solution: update java.  After I did that, everything worked smoothly again!

I'm guessing that could endpoints now require Java version 1.7.0_51-b13 or later, judging by [this comment](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/reflect/Types.java?r=bf37714cb4480fc2c52b759bb755f6aa617cb347#496) in the source of the Guava class that was giving us trouble.

For reference, the version of Java 7 available today is 1.7.0_76.